# useEffect runs infinitely when using setState inside of it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop, peerjs

I am working on a group video chat. I am having an issue about using useEffect.
Let me explain the problem.
Here's my code that runs inside a useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const callOthers = async () => {
    if (callOthersTriggered) {
      const selfStream = await getMedia();
      setPeersOnConference((prev) => ({ ...prev, [peer.id]: selfStream }));
      for (const remotePeer in peersOnConference) {
        if (remotePeer === peer.id) continue;
        const call = peer.call(remotePeer, selfStream);
        call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
          setPeersOnConference((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [call.peer]: remoteStream,
          }));
        });
      }
    }
  };
  callOthers();
}, [callOthersTriggered, peer, peersOnConference]);
```

I want to run the code snippet only when the callOthersTriggered value is true. Also I am iterating the keys of the peersOnConference object and setting the values of the keys simultaneously. For that purpose I needed to add this object in the dependency array which actually causing the infinite loop. What changes should I make to fix this issue and also achieve the functionality? Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `peersOnConference` from the dependency list. as it causes the useEffect to run again and again when you are doing setPeersOnConference inside the useEffect.
so the code will become

```
useEffect(() => {
  const callOthers = async () => {
    if (callOthersTriggered) {
      const selfStream = await getMedia();
      setPeersOnConference((prev) => ({ ...prev, [peer.id]: selfStream }));
      for (const remotePeer in peersOnConference) {
        if (remotePeer === peer.id) continue;
        const call = peer.call(remotePeer, selfStream);
        call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
          setPeersOnConference((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [call.peer]: remoteStream,
          }));
        });
      }
    }
  };
  callOthers();
}, [callOthersTriggered, peer]);
```